# White token in Catan cities and knights

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

Catan cities and knights has four colored circular tokens.  There is a yellow, blue, and green to indicate when someone has acquired the metropolis for trade, politics and science respectively.  There are also a white and grey one.  My question is what are the white and grey one for?  I couldn't find any reference to it in the rules.

Comment: Which edition do you have? I have the original wood edition and the chips for the metropolis are all the same color, and there is no additional chip in the box.

Comment: I have the 5th edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a spare piece. Usually these kinds of tokens are printed on a sheet of cardboard that's big enough to fit in the game box, and if there's a bit of extra space then a few extra things might be put on the board to fill the space. Those tokens can then be used as replacements for the main tokens - so if, for example, you lost the green one, you can just state that the grey token replaces the green.